# Edit, update, delete for angular list

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, list

I have a json object in angular

```
[
    {
        "orderNumber": 5821784,
        "accountNumber": 167067702,
        "taskCodes": {
            "3": 1,
            "5": 1,
            "23": 1,
            "51": 1,
            "71": 1
        },
        "orderCode": "TC",
        "orderState": 0
    },
    {
        "orderNumber": 5821785,
        "accountNumber": 167067703,
        "taskCodes": {
            "23": 1,
            "41": 1,
            "51": 1
        },
        "orderCode": "TC",
        "orderState": 0
    }
]
```

i need to update, delete and add new taskCodes in taskCodes list.

Here is my html code :-

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">

                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Code</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead> 
                        <tbody>
                            <tr data-ng-repeat="(key, taskCode) in Obj.taskCodes">
                                <td>
                                    <span data-ng-hide="editMode[$index]">{{key}}</span>
                                    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" data-ng-model="key" data-ng-show="editMode[$index]">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span data-ng-hide="editMode[$index]"> {{taskCode}} </span>
                                    <input type="number" class="input-sm form-control" data-ng-model="taskCode" data-ng-show="editMode[$index]" >
                                </td> 
                                <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit accordion-toggle clickable" data-ng-hide="editMode[$index]" data-ng-click="edit($index)"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok accordion-toggle clickable" data-ng-hide="!editMode[$index]" data-ng-click="addItem($index)"></span>
</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Controller Edit function :-

```
$scope.items = [];

    $scope.addItem = function () {
     //Need code here
    }

    $scope.editMode=[];
    $scope.edit = function(index) {
        $scope.editMode[index] = true;
    };
```

Can someone please help me to do all that.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It should work in the way the code is right now. I think this is not the actual code however. I bet the $scope.items variable is undefined in the moment you try to push, test that.

Comment: I agree with Victor, might be related to some other code. Also not related I guess but there is a semicolon missing at the end of $scope.addItem = function () {} ...

Comment: @victor and Sebasti now i update my question please check it. and thanks for your reply

Comment: Try the code you had before, but do:  
`if (!(Object.prototype.toString.call($scope.items) === '[object Array]')) {
    $scope.items = [];
}`
 As a first operation.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer

> var o = {
>               "23": 1,
>               "41": 1,
>               "51": 1
>           }
>
> console.log(o)
>
> delete o[41];
>
> console.log(o)
>
> o[56] = 5; console.log(o)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it following way!

```
 $scope.jsonObject.key.push(value);
```

Replace `jsonObject` with your object name and same with the key and value pair!
I hope the solution would work for you!

Comment: @konrda i just update my question please check now. and thanks for your reply